Dark baking pan versus light baking pan
There are a ton of articles on baking websites that state baking in a dark colored pan works different than using a light colored pan.
The only thing I can think of is that the pans are of different thickness or a different material/density.
So if I have two exact same pans, one of a light color and the other of a dark color, will the item in the dark colored pan cook faster?

I'd say, "sounds like an experiment you can do at home," but there's probably a few more variables to consider besides just the color. Can you find two pans, same dimensions, made of the same weight of the same material, with the same finish/coating,... With the only difference between the two being the color?

@SolomonSlow Very true, but you can also take the other approach right? Do it with many different pans of all kinds of materials, coating, etc. but such that half of them are of the same~ dark color and the other half are of the same~ bright color, and test for the required correlation...

@Amit, True enough. I guess it's time to start writing a grant application.

@SolomonSlow Chromo-thermodynamics :)

One way it might matter is that dark colors absorb light while light colors reflect it. Dark and light are defined in the visible spectrum, but absorption spectra can be extended into the infrared.
Heating elements in an electric oven generate a lot of infrared radiation. If they are especially hot, they even emit into the red. This radiation is reflected by the oven walls and is absorbed by the food in the oven. This is one of the prime heating mechanisms in the oven. (The other would be the heating element heats the air and the air heats the food.)
If you put the food in a baking dish that reflects infrared, the food is partially shielded. It will take longer to get hot.
Food that is heated quickly tends to cook on the outside more and the inside less. If heat gets in slowly, the food tends to have a more uniform temperature and cook evenly. It doesn't sound like shielding would make heating more uniform. It might make the top cook more than the bottom.
A dish that absorbs infrared will get hot quickly and the dish will heat the food. This might help develop a crust on the bottom of the food.

As an avid pie maker, I'll tell you that it is very effective to cover the outside crust of your pie with tin foil about half way through the cooking cycle.  This stops the outside crust from overbaking or burning while the rest of the pie continues to cook. This would be because of the higly reflective nature of tin foil.  So yes, a light coloured pan would certainly reflect more of the radiated heat than a dark coloured pan.
